# redux state not updating despite action firing

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

Pls I encountered some behavior with my redux store which I don't understand.

My `store.dispatch` doesn't trigger changes despite calling the reducer when called from js class.

My store is like below :

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export default () => {
    const store = createStore(
        persistedReducer,
        composeWithDevTools(
            applyMiddleware(thunk),
            // other store enhancers if any
        )
    );
    const persistor = persistStore(store);
    store.subscribe(() => console.log("An action has ben fired here "));
    return { store, persistor }
}
```

Which I imported within an Axios middleware class like below

```
const { store } = storeConfig();
```

I then use it to dispatch an action

```
store.dispatch(toggleNotification(notification));
```

to my surprise, the state never get updated despite calling the reducer
I added a console at

```
case TOGGLE_NOTIFICATION: {
    console.log("Does it reach the reducer ?", action.notification)
    return state.set("notification", fromJS(action.notification));
}
```

and the message gets triggered by my action

```
export function toggleNotification(notification: NotificationProps) {
    return { 
        type: constants.TOGGLE_NOTIFICATION, 
        notification,
    }
}
```

To my surprise, notification state never get updated, Also my redux  dev tool doesn't register the `TOGGLE_NOTIFICATION` type action, yet registers all other actions.

Pls what am I missing and why is my action not firing properly?
This only happens when I fire from `store.dispatch`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you wrap the store config in a function :

```
export default () => {
    const store = createStore(...)
    return { store, persistor }
}
```

and so when you call it in `const { store } = storeConfig();` within the Axios middleware, you're creating a new store object, which is probably not the one used in the rest of your app.

So you can just remove the function, like this :

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        // other store enhancers if any
    )
);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
store.subscribe(() => console.log("An action has ben fired here "));

export default { store, persistor }
```

And then use the same store like this :

```
import storeConfig from './path/to/storeConfig';

const { store } = storeConfig;
store.dispatch(toggleNotification(notification));
```

Comment: Thank you . That was indeed the issue. But i think the default in your export is not necessary :).

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're doing a state-mutation instead of returning a completely new `state` object.

Redux follows the JavaScript principle that objects can share the same reference in memory.  So if you are making an update to an existing object, like by doing:

```
return state.set("blah")
```

Redux does not register that as a brand new `state`, since that's the same object being returned.

It's not entirely clear what your code is doing, but we can operate under the premise that you should always create or return a brand new `state` object.

We can possibly resolve this by just deep-cloning the initial state object before using any methods on it.

```
case TOGGLE_NOTIFICATION: {
            const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
            return newState.set("notification", fromJS(action.notification));
        }
```

Comment: Hi, i am using immutable js here https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js and the set function comes from the immutable class. To my undertsnading, it shouldn't mutate at all or should it ?

Comment: Hmm, to be honest I'm not too familiar with that library. It might not necessarily mutate the object, but it still might be using the same object ya know? Unless there's a guarantee that they're not using the same object in memory. @NuruSalihu

Comment: No Christopher, it doesn't mutate. I confirm, also i tried your code above. It doesn't trigger regardless :)

Comment: @NuruSalihu it sounds like your other actions work. I wonder if it just has to do with where you're calling this aciton from.

Comment: That i suspect, but it should work according to the documentation.

Comment: @NuruSalihu if you want to create a sandbox, i don't mind debugging it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very stupid mistake on this, I am sure nobody would make that kind of a stupid mistake but anyhow here is another mistake that could prevent redux state from updating, on your reducer:

```
return {foo:"new value", ...state}
```

will not update your state if `foo` already exists in the previous state. So instead of this, add the state first then update `foo` like so

```
return {...state, foo:"new value"}
```

happy coding...